# How would you express the phrasing “Courtesy of [x]” in Japanese?

Tags: grammar, politeness, english-to-japanese, keigo

I’m having a bit of trouble figuring out how to phrase this sort of thing. I’m thinking of this in the context of “acknowledging that someone has formally done a service for another”.

Examples might be: some kind of event presented to its guests *courtesy of* their sponsor, a delivery completed *courtesy of* a shipping service, a gift given *courtesy of* the help of someone else.

Alternatively, yourself providing a gracious service to another person—“courtesy of yours truly”? I’d like to get a comparison of what to do versus what *not* to do when trying to say something like this, if possible. I’m  not sure how you would approach this sort of phrasing politely, versus politely-but-arrogantly.

I feel like this must be a grammatical construction/keigo thing, but I’m not sure whether it’s something you’d use sonkeigo or teneigo, etc. for?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [提供](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%8F%90%E4%BE%9B) like this:

- この写真はAによる提供です。
  This picture is courtesy of A.
- 無料WiFi提供: A
  Free WiFi courtesy of A
- 本イベントのライブ配信はAの提供でお送りします。
  Live coverage of the event is courtesy of A.
- お菓子はAに提供していただきました。
  These snacks are courtesy of A.

Comment: この番組はコナミとご覧のスポンサーの提供でお送りします

Comment: @Angelos exactly where my mind went, although I wasn't aware of Konami being a common enough sponsor to get called out separately like that... ?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I was very specifically thinking of Yu-Gi-Oh! actually

Comment: Ah, that would make sense then.

Answer (score 1):

You could use おかげで, for example (taken from [WWWJDIC](http://nihongo.monash.edu/cgi-bin/wwwjdic?1Q%A4%AA%B1%A2%A4%C7_1_)):

- 彼の尽力のおかげで、それは予期以上の成功であった。
  Thanks to his efforts, it was more successful than we had expected.
- 彼らのおかげで私はやっと元気になった。
  Thanks to them, I got well at last.
- この機会のおかげで私たちは大いに手間暇が省けた。
  Thanks to the opportunity, we were able to avoid substantial effort.

提供 relates to providing, offering or donating something, whereas おかげ implies a more causal relationship (and can also be either positive or negative, e.g. "I was late to work thanks to my broken alarm clock"). You can also use [おかげさまで](http://nihongo.monash.edu/cgi-bin/wwwjdic?1MDJ%A4%AA%A4%AB%A4%B2%A4%B5%A4%DE%A4%C7), which is commonly used to express thanks for someone's assistance.